# $http service not triggered success handler within controller angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am working on AngularJS application. After initially build basic application I have move to routing in angular. I have successfully implemented routing. My data from previous pages comes to page I am routing using `$routeParams`.

Inside my controller I am calling $http service with input received from `$routeParams` service. I all REST API and in network tab of chrome i see response coming back but my success handler of http service not called.Tried to debug but breakpoint is never reached.

Here is my routing configuration:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']); 
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl:"main.html",
        controller:'CategoriesController'
    }).when('/imagedetails/:imageId',{
        templateUrl: 'imagedetails.html',
        controller:'ImageDetailsController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

});
```

So i pass `imageId` to ImageDetailsController to fetch data from REST API.

Here is my controller:

```
 var ImageDetailsController = function($scope, $http, $routeParams)
    {
        $scope.imageId = $routeParams.imageId;
        console.log("Print image id : " + $scope.imageId);
        $scope.image = {};
        $scope.params = $routeParams;

         var downloadImageRequest = {
                 method: 'GET',
                 url: '<my-rest-api-url>',
                 headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                 }
        };

        $http(downloadImageRequest).then(onImageSuccess, onImageFailure);

        var onImageSuccess = function(response){ // i have put debug inside this method but never reaches controller
            console.log(response  );
            $scope.image = response.data.results[0];
        };
        var onImageFailure = function(response){
            alert("Failed to load image please try again!!");
             console.log(response);
        };
    }
```

In Network tab of chrome developer tool, response is visible but above method in which I set response not triggered.

Please help

Comment: So you can see the data coming back in dev tools?, first remove the headers, you don't need that. Also the failure callback is executed?

Comment: yes i see data in dev tools... no callback is triggered. To make sure i used console.log()

Comment: can you remove headers and try

Comment: Define first the two variables and then use them. You are using both onImageSuccess and onImageFailure before defining them.

Comment: @LeandroZubrezki thanks. Small mistake because of being newbie in js. It worked.

Comment: This question just made me wonder what valid use cases for calling ```then``` with all callbacks undefined exist? If there are none I think implementations might do well to throw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first define your variables and then use them. Defining a variable is different than defining a function. So you can:

```
    var onImageSuccess = function(response){
        console.log(response  );
        $scope.image = response.data.results[0];
    };

    var onImageFailure = function(response){
        alert("Failed to load image please try again!!");
         console.log(response);
    };

    $http(downloadImageRequest).then(onImageSuccess, onImageFailure);
```

or you can do it defining a named function:

```
    $http(downloadImageRequest).then(onImageSuccess, onImageFailure);

    function onImageSuccess(response){ // i have put debug inside this method but never reaches controller
        console.log(response  );
        $scope.image = response.data.results[0];
    }

    function onImageFailure(response){
        alert("Failed to load image please try again!!");
         console.log(response);
    }
```

Comment: I personally prefer the bottom definition. Mainly because it always prevents you running into these issues. You don't need to see the implementation all the time, but you always need to see at a glance what is going on.

Comment: I also prefer named functions instead of variables, :)